# SymPy: using solve in Euler's identity

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to use `sympy.solve` for some simple physics problems, but I am facing a couple of problems with the exact usage. Therefore I went back a bit and tried `solve` on an even simpler problem: finding the identity

```
sin(x) = (exp(i*x) - exp(-i*x)) / 2i
```

Just as a test, but somehow I can not make SymPy find the correct solution.

First I tested `cos(x)`:

```
import sympy as smp
a, b = smp.symbols('a b', real=True)
x = smp.symbols('x', real=True)
```

I defined the equation:

```
eq1 = smp.Eq(smp.cos(x), a * smp.exp(smp.I * x) + b * smp.exp(- smp.I * x))
```

and then solve it:

```
smp.solve(eq1, (a, b))
>>> {a: 1/2, b: 1/2}
```

which is, of course, correct.

But if I now look for the sin(x) function:

```
c, d = smp.symbols('c d', complex=True)
eq2 = smp.Eq(smp.sin(x), c * smp.exp(smp.I * x) + d * smp.exp(- smp.I * x))
smp.solve(eq2, (c, d))
>>> [((-d + exp(I*x)*sin(x))*exp(-2*I*x), d)]
```

The solver does not work.

I know, I can make it work with the following:

```
eq3 = smp.Eq(smp.sin(x), a * smp.I * smp.exp(smp.I * x) + b * smp.I * smp.exp(- smp.I * x))
smp.solve(eq3, (a, b))
>>> {a: -1/2, b: 1/2}
```

but this is somehow cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are solving a single equation for two unknowns. In the case that the unknowns (a and b) are real then since the equation has non-trivial real and imaginary parts they can be separated to make two real equations for two real unknowns.

Where the unknowns (c and d) are themselves not necessarily real you are solving one complex equation for two complex unknowns. This is equivalent to having two real equations for four real unknowns.

What this means is that `solve(eq2, (c, d))` finds that the system is undetermined and so returns a parametrised solution set for the system. The returned solution is valid for any possible value of `d`:

```
In [30]: sol = solve(eq2, (c, d), dict=True)[0]

In [31]: sol
Out[31]: 
⎧   ⎛      ⅈ⋅x       ⎞  -2⋅ⅈ⋅x⎫
⎨c: ⎝-d + ℯ   ⋅sin(x)⎠⋅ℯ      ⎬
⎩                             ⎭

In [32]: eq2.subs(sol)
Out[32]: 
            -ⅈ⋅x   ⎛      ⅈ⋅x       ⎞  -ⅈ⋅x
sin(x) = d⋅ℯ     + ⎝-d + ℯ   ⋅sin(x)⎠⋅ℯ    

In [33]: eq2.subs(sol).expand()
Out[33]: True
```

An alternative would be to set `c` and `d` to be imaginary:

```
In [51]: c, d = smp.symbols('c d', imaginary=True)

In [52]: eq2 = smp.Eq(smp.sin(x), c * smp.exp(smp.I * x) + d * smp.exp(- smp.I * x))

In [53]: solve(eq2, (c, d))
Out[53]: 
⎧   -ⅈ      ⅈ⎫
⎨c: ───, d: ─⎬
⎩    2      2⎭
```